# Count email adresses in profile from adress book

Tags: ios, swift, casting

In my app I can access to the device address book, for selecting a contact and getting his email.

Because of contacts that don't have any email, I have to count the number of email address. If I don't, I can get a `nil` value and the app crashes.

I tried a lot of ways but I'm always having problems to do it.

When I write this code :

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {
    var emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty) as! ABMultiValueRef
    var countEmails = ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)
```

I get this error :

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Unmanaged<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x7f9f12db3c88) to 'Swift.AnyObject'
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting iOS 9? Some of these apis have been deprecated.

- `kABPersonEmailProperty` should be `CNContact.emailAddresses`
- `ABMultiValueRef` should be `[CNLabeledValue]`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get all email address in array

```
let emailProperty: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef        

let allEmailIDs: NSArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray

for email in allEmailIDs 
{            
    let emailID = email as String
    println ("contactEmail : \(emailID) :=>")
}
```

If you want to check the number of email count then use

```
let allEmailIDs: NSArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
```

So I added a check just before to make sure there are any emails.

```
if ABMultiValueGetCount(emailProperty) > 0 {
  let allEmailIDs: NSArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
}
```